# Given a set of permutations return one specific number

Tags: python, list, numbers, permutation

I want your help to catch an specific number or any number that I asked for in bool_check in this case that number is "4321" so i've been struggling to get True and also I want the program to show me that specific number from this set of permutations.
For example, I want the output to say:
True
4321
So far i got the permutations and the functions but i dont know how to connect everything. Thank you for your time.

```
from itertools import product

def bool_check(x):
    
    if x == "4321":
        return True
    else:
        return False

      
def find_key(diferent_dig, quantity_dig):
    
    chars = list(diferent_dig)
    perms = []
    for c in product(chars, repeat = quantity_dig):
        perms.append(c)

        
    return perms

print(find_key("1234", 4))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product` returns a tuple of the items, but you are searching for a string.

Eg. `(1, 2, 3, 4)` instead of `1234`

I am not too sure what you are after but maybe something like this will help:

```
from itertools import product

def find_key(diferent_dig, quantity_dig):
   chars = list(diferent_dig)
   perms = []
   for c in product(chars, repeat = quantity_dig):
       perms.append(''.join(c)) # Convert from tuple to String
   return perms

print("1234" in find_key("1234", 4)) # returns True
print("5555" in find_key("1234", 4)) # returns False
```